# Weighted Cluster Algorithm using ns2?

Tags: ns2, weighted, clustering-key

I have tried to implement WCA for ad hoc but I could only set up a ad hoc network and unable to cluster. So please help me on this.

Comment: Could you provide more informations on your problem ? like what environement, what did you try so far, where are you stuck ?

Comment: how to calculate residual energy, mobility  and estimate no. of neighbors.